# AKS exposing application using HTTP application routing

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm trying to expose application using HTTP application routing. I enabled http_application_routing addons which is result in this config :

```
  "addonProfiles": {
    "httpapplicationrouting": {
      "config": {
        "HTTPApplicationRoutingZoneName": "****.northeurope.aksapp.io",
        "httpapplicationroutingzonename": "****.northeurope.aksapp.io"
      },
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
```

I created ingress resource :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
  labels:
    name: axon-azure
  name: axon-ing-azure
spec:
  rules:
  - host: axon.****.northeurope.aksapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: axon-svc
          servicePort: 8024
        path: /
```

But it doesn't work when I test it :

```
curl axon.****.northeurope.aksapp.io
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: axon.****.northeurope.aksapp.io
```

Following the AKS documentation, I'm thinking about a DNS problem because the DNS zone name doesn't appear using this command (but I don't know why) :

```
az aks show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --query addonProfiles.httpApplicationRouting.config.HTTPApplicationRoutingZoneName -o table
```

Any idea of what's going wrong in this case ?

Comment: Please let know if the answer is helpful for your question!

Comment: @Nicolas Pepinster Does answer below was useful ?

Answer (score 0):

For the HTTP application routing in AKS, when you enable the routing feature using the CLI command:

```
az aks enable-addons --resource-group your_resource_group --name your_akscluster --addons http_application_routing
```

If there is no error, then you can get the DNS zone that Azure creates for you through the CLI command:

```
az aks show --resource-group your_resource_group --name your_akscluster --query addonProfiles.httpApplicationRouting.config.HTTPApplicationRoutingZoneName -o table
```

In the above two CLI commands, you need to change the `your_resource_group` and `your_akscluster` with your own group and AKS.

And after you create the ingress with the yaml file, you should wait a bit long time which Azure create the record for you in the DNS zone. Maybe 5 minutes are needed. You can take a look if the record is already in the DNS zone.

If you need the HTTP route, I will suggest you create it yourself following the steps in [Create an ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic) or [Use a static IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip). In this way, you will know exactly which step you have done or mistake.

Comment: Like I said in my question, the addons was enabled (see json) and an HTTP application routing domain is defined (`****.northeurope.aksapp.io`) however, the `aks show` command doesn't return anything (already said in my question). 

Maybe I don't have enough right to make this query ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster How do you create the AKS cluster and enable the addons? If you can see it through the command `az aks show --resource-group your_resource_group --name your_akscluster`? Why does it show two `httpapplicationroutingzonename` in the config?